# finding if an element exists within a nested dict in python. (simulating a shelf)

Tags: python

I am quite to programming and running to some issue. I am also new to posting here.

I am trying to make a program to look and see if an item is the shelf.
I have a shelf with bins at each row. My goal was to 1) check if an item exists in one of the bin and 2) print the location on the screen.

```
shelf1 = {
  'row0' : {
    'bin1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
    'bin2': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6'],
    'bin3': ['A7', 'A8', 'A9']
  },
  'row1' : {
    'bin1': ['A10'],
    'bin2': ['A11', 'A12', 'A13'],
    'bin3': ['A14', 'A15']
  },
  'row2' : {
    'bin1': ['A16', 'A17', 'A18'],
    'bin2': ['A19'],
    'bin3': ['A20', 'A21', 'A22']
  },
  'row3' : {
    'bin1': ['A23'],
    'bin2': ['A24'],
    'bin3': ['A25']
  }
}


testShelf = [shelf1]
strShelf = ['shelf1]

while True:
  assm = input('what board are you looking for? ').upper()
  print(assm)
  for shelf in testShelf:
    shlfNum = testShelf.index(shelf)
    for i, j in shelf.items():
      temp1 = i
      for k,l in j.items():
        temp2 = k
        if assm in l:
          shlf = strShelf[shlfNum]
          row = temp1
          bin = temp2

  try:
    if shlf and row and bin is None:
      print('item does not exist')
    else:
      print(shlf, row, bin)
  except NameError:
    print('invalid board assembly. Please try again')
```

I am trying to print an error if the user typed an non-existing item, but the for some reason getting the previous location when entered.

output:

```
shelf1 row0 bin1
what board are you looking for? a2
A2
shelf1 row0 bin1
what board are you looking for? a5 
A5
shelf1 row0 bin2
what board are you looking for? a90
A90
shelf1 row0 bin2
```

so far tried to play around the for loop to see the output.
tried to add an else statement to change the values of shlf, row and bin

```
if assm in l:
  shlf = strShelf[shlfNum]
  row = temp1
  bin = temp2
else:
  shlf = None
  row = None
  bin = None
```

I got 'None None None' as the output

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is with the placement of the try-except block. Currently, it surrounds the check for shlf, row, and bin, which can lead to incorrect output. Instead, you should move the try-except block to only handle the assignment of shlf, row, and bin when the item is found

```
shelf1 = {
  'row0': {
    'bin1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
    'bin2': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6'],
    'bin3': ['A7', 'A8', 'A9']
  },
  'row1': {
    'bin1': ['A10'],
    'bin2': ['A11', 'A12', 'A13'],
    'bin3': ['A14', 'A15']
  },
  'row2': {
    'bin1': ['A16', 'A17', 'A18'],
    'bin2': ['A19'],
    'bin3': ['A20', 'A21', 'A22']
  },
  'row3': {
    'bin1': ['A23'],
    'bin2': ['A24'],
    'bin3': ['A25']
  }
}

testShelf = [shelf1]
strShelf = ['shelf1']

while True:
  assm = input('What board are you looking for? ').upper()
  print(assm)
  shlf = None 
  row = None
  bin = None

  for shelf in testShelf:
    shlfNum = testShelf.index(shelf)
    for i, j in shelf.items():
      temp1 = i
      for k, l in j.items():
        temp2 = k
        if assm in l:
          shlf = strShelf[shlfNum]
          row = temp1
          bin = temp2
          break  
      if shlf is not None: 
        break
    if shlf is not None:
      break

  try:
    if shlf is None or row is None or bin is None:
      print('Item does not exist')
    else:
      print(shlf, row, bin)
  except NameError:
    print('Invalid board assembly. Please try again')
```

Comment: correct me if im wrong. the issue was that I was looking for shlf, row, and bin to be None instead of check one of them?